# Output date in Javascript as string

Tags: php, javascript, string, date, tostring

could you please advice how to output `2012-08-11` in JavaScript as a string without it
 showing the results as integer i.e. `1993`. I have tried using the `.toString()` function but 
 that doesn't work - it stills output it as  `1993`.

I'm parsing the date `2012-08-11` to a JavaScript function via PHP.

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you show us the PHP *and* Javascript you're using, enough to replicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$year  = 2008;
$month = 8;
$day   = 11; 

echo "<script>";
echo "alert( $year + '-' + $month + '-' + $day )";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UgavXa)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date(),
    txt = d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate();
alert(d.toUTCString());
alert(d.toDateString());
alert(txt);
```

For more information, please refer to [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)